# Overriding SensioGeneratorBundle's twig template: trying to translate the delete button

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to override `Resources/crud/actions/delete.php.twig` from SensioGeneratorBundle.

I created this file located at `app/Resources/SensioGeneratorBundle/skeleton/crud/actions/delete.php.twig`:

```
{% extends "@SensioGenerator/Resources/crud/actions/delete.php.twig" %}

{% block form %}
    /**
     * Creates a form to delete a {{ entity }} entity by id.
     *
     * @param mixed $id The entity id
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createDeleteForm($id)
    {
        return $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('{{ route_name_prefix }}_delete', array('id' => $id)))
            ->setMethod('DELETE')
            ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Supprimer'))
            ->getForm()
        ;
    }
{% endblock form %}
```

Problem is that `@SensioGenerator` is not recognized:

> There are no registered paths for namespace "SensioGenerator" in "crud/controller.php.twig" at line 58.

I tried to manually register the namespace in `app/config/config.yml`:

```
twig:
    [...]
    paths:
        "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/sensio/generator-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/GeneratorBundle/": SensioGenerator
```

But still not working.  Idea?

Comment: I see that you are trying to override the `block` form only, and then extend from the original `delete.php.twig`. I tried replicating your issue, and I have encountered the same issue. A bit strange... I guess the quickest/easiest, though not necessarily purest, solution is to override the entire file, change the parts you want to change and avoid the `extends` directive altogether. That definitely works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you didn't do it like in docs ? [SensioGeneratorDocs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/index.html)

```
{% extends "skeleton/crud/actions/delete.php.twig" %}

{% block form %}
    /**
    * Creates a form to delete a {{ entity }} entity by id.
    *
    * @param mixed $id The entity id
    *
    * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
    */
    private function createDeleteForm($id)
    {
    return $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->setAction($this->generateUrl('{{ route_name_prefix }}_delete', array('id' => $id)))
    ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Supprimer'))
    ->getForm()
    ;
    }
{% endblock form %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a project that's based-on or is similar-to the [Symfony Standard Edition](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/), then the SensioGeneratorBundle is only loaded for the `dev` environment.

This is configured in both the [composer.json](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.7/composer.json#L23) and the [AppKernel](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.7/app/AppKernel.php#L26).

So, make sure your execution is using the `dev` environment or alter these configurations so that the bundle is always loaded.